# Can not use Fieldset with PrimeNG in Angular 14

Tags: angular, primeng, fieldset

I was trying to use the Fieldset I saw in [PrimeNG docs.](http://primefaces.org/primeng/fieldset)

I take the code below from there

```
<p-fieldset legend="Header">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</p-fieldset>
```

And add it into my project. But intead of a fieldset, I get the output below.

[image]

Also here is my imports from app.module.ts (I sign the ones probably you're looking for.)

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule, <----
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, <----
    DropdownModule,
    FormsModule,
    PanelModule,
    MultiSelectModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TableModule,
    ButtonModule,
    DialogModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    ToastModule,
    MessageModule,
    MessagesModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    FieldsetModule, <----
  ],
```

Is there is a way to make it work like in the docs?

EDIT:
Also, my angular.json file is here:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "sorusturma-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/sorusturma-angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "sorusturma-angular:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "sorusturma-angular:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "sorusturma-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you add prime-related style URLs in the angular.json file?

Comment: Please ensure you've added the style files to angular.json as shown in the docs: http://primefaces.org/primeng/setup. Then share your angular.json if it is not working.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Yes I have style links in my angular.json file. I add the file in to the post. I use a lot of primeng modules and all of them works perfectly except this one.

Comment: hi I have the same issue did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, unfortunately.